# Does marking a PHP parameter that defaults to NULL as nullable make any difference?

Tags: php, parameters, nullable, type-hinting

Consider the following method signature:

```
public function foo(bool $flag = null);
```

Versus this signature:

```
public function foo(?bool $flag = null);
```

Does that nullable operator make any practical difference?

Comment: There is no difference between these two declarations